# Is a https connection recommended for server receipt verification under iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm setting up a server to do receipt verification for IAP on the App Store.

My question is: Should I make the connection between the iOS device and **my server** as a https connection, or does http suffice?  All the examples I seen people are just using http.

It seems that if I use http, then it's venerable to a someone redirecting the DNS.  Or does that not matter?  Seems like it would.

Of course, I'm such small potatoes that it's probably not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

It is always desirable to use https (encrypted) connection when you are passing some credentials or sensitive information such as financial transactions. May be it is not possible for anyone to mangle the transaction itself but still, you are breaching the confidentiality aspect of financial transactions which your client might not like.

However, it is not just https which can help, you can also implement your custom encryption in the application to make the communication secure (may be the security is not strong but does work in cases where you really do not need an overkill). Try to encrypt the data with a pre-shared key and decrypt it on the server (which I do myself many times).